# Why does \renewcommand not overwrite \includegraphics from tikzscale?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikzscale

I have the following tex code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}% 
  \framebox{\rule{0pt}{0.6\linewidth}\rule{\linewidth}{0pt}}% 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{tikzpicture.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid (3,3);
\foreach \c in {(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (2,1), (1,2)}
    \fill \c + (0.5,0.5) circle (0.42);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{tikzpicture.tikz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `\renewcomand` overwrites the `\includegraphics` and replaces all my pixel images with frameboxes for faster compile time during document writing. However the images with a .tikz extension still get loaded.

As far as I understand it `tikzscale` overwrites the `\includegraphics` from `graphicx` and I overwrite it with my definition. Why does this not work? Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Thats a nice way of speeding up document creation! Especially when `\tikzexternalize` doesn´t work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package `tikzscale` delays its redefinition of `\includegraphics` at begin document, so you should do

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}% 
    \framebox{\rule{0pt}{0.6\linewidth}\rule{\linewidth}{0pt}}% 
  }%
}
```

as well.